# EntityFramework relations one-many-(Insert help here) - eager-loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 4 models

1. Factory
2. Car
3. TypeA
4. TypeB

Factory can have many cars, a Car can have TypeA and TypeB. Both TypeA and TypeB can exist on the car
i.e im using [eager-loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)
So my models would look like

```
public class Factory
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int FactoryID {get;set;}

    public ICollection<Car> Cars {get;set;}
}

public class Car
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CarID {get;set;}

    public int FactoryID {get;set;}
    public Factory Factory {get;set;}

    //The Types
    public TypeA TypeA {get;set;}
    public TypeB TypeB {get;set;}
}

public class TypeA
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TypeAID {get;set;}

    [Key, ForeignKey("Car")]
    public int CarID {get;set;}
    public Car Car {get;set;}
}

public class TypeB
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TypeBID {get;set;}

    [Key, ForeignKey("Car")]
    public int CarID {get;set;}
    public Car Car {get;set;}
}
```

Here is my problem. How do I load both TypeA and TypeB into my Factory Object (using Eager-Loading)

```
Factory factory = db.Factory.Where(f => f.FactoryID == 1).Include(f => f.Cars.Select(c => c.TypeA) ... .FirstOrDefault();
```

Because I cannot say

```
Include(f=>f.Cars.Select(...).Select(...))
```

Comment: You can repeat the `Include` statement, with typeB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just chain the `include` statement:

```
Factory factory = db.Factory.Where(f => f.FactoryID == 1)
                            .Include(f => f.Cars.Select(c => c.TypeA))
                            .Include(f => f.Cars.Select(c => c.TypeB))
                            ....;
```

By the way:
It may would make sense to introduce a base class for `TypeA` and `TypeB` - or even just use one class, since I don't see a difference between the two of them.

Comment: There is a definite distinction between the two, I just abstracted the whole thing a bit for SO :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple include statements. There is no need to only have one.